# how can add multiple checkbox using mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I search so many times but , did not work please help me 
how to add a CheckBox see my screen shot one's a click of checkbox  should be check them all and able to uncheck other checkbox
thank you

Comment: you can use JS for doing that if you are allowed to do !!!

Comment: You code needs to be in the question - not a link to an image of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by clicking on any checkbox with class `.w3-check` than check all checkboxes which have same class instead of checking all the checkboxes of current page..

```
   $(".w3-check").on("change",function(){
    if(this.checked)
    {
      $(".w3-check").prop('checked', this.checked);
    }
   });
```

Comment: thanks for a lot , yes!! thanks for helping work it... thank you thank you for your support..

Comment: That's great you are always welcome glad to help you Cheers :)

Comment: thanks Curious , thanks for info did well

Comment: hi sir , i had something problem, how can can i uncheck one of them please help

Comment: thanks sir , i try this thank you sa much

Comment: sir I cannot  see my check box sir , after i put them to my code I cannot see any check box

Comment: hi sir, see my updated whole code above how to add checkbox using jquery able to uncheck and check thank you

Comment: @J.Cloud in your code i didn't find any checkboxes there are only hidden fields and UL > LI

Comment: wait sir , I update my code

Comment: hi sir, see my update

Comment: From your code seems like this checkbox is only for **administrator** login  are you login as administrator? like this condition `@if (isAdministrator)
                                    {
                                        @Html.CheckBox("[" + @counter + "].IsSelected", item.Item.IsSelected, new { @class = "w3-check" })

                                    }
`

Comment: yes only admin can check them all and uncheck

Comment: how to add a checkbox on top

Comment: how do i add check box on top

Comment: hi sir , are you there?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jQuery. Here's a sample code:

```js
 
$(".w3-check").click(function(){
  $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>1</label> 
<input type="checkbox" class="w3-check"/> 
<label>2</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="w3-check"/>
<label>3</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="w3-check"/>
<label>4</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="w3-check"/>
```

Comment: and also thank you prtdomingo thanks lot

Comment: hi sir , i had something problem, how can can i uncheck one of them please help

Comment: Someone help me please...

Comment: anyone can help me?